# Building reports from an XML data sources

Tags: xml, reportbuilder

I'm looking for a graphically oriented D&D type tool/utility that can be used to build ad hoc reports from data contained in XML data files. The users are technical, but not developers -- so XSLT is right out...

Eclipse' BIRT does this kind of thing, but something more lightweight is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

just some basic list of (commercial) tools which you could have a look at:

- Attached XML schema in MS Word
- Microsoft InfoPath
- Windward Reports (also MS Word based)
- Altova Stylevision